# How to bind to express route some function which returns Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

How do I bind a function returning a *promise* to an express route?

I have a function that works with my model objects which returns promises and I need to add it to controller function which *react* on a particular express route:

```
app.get('/students/list', controllerFunction);
```

(I have function `findAllActiveStudents` which read from file/database and returns promise).
How to write controllerFunction which inside call `findAllActiveStudents` and returns result ?

```
// inside controller file
exports controllerFunction = function(req, res) {

     // Here what to do

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It can possibly be used like this:

```
// inside controller file
exports controllerFunction = function(req, res) {

    var promise = findAllActiveStudents(req);

    promise.then(function(result) {
        // format and send the result
        res.send(result);
    }, function(err) {
        // format and send the error
        res.send(error);
    });
}
```